# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined with Object

Tags: javascript

First of all, I'm not a frontend dev and I don't know a lot about JavaScript, so please have patience with my question, I'll be grateful, but I need to solve this "typical" error but I cannot find in the google, stackoverflow how to solve, Let's say that in the code, in some way it works, but before of this current solution it was this way:

Where is correct but it's not "pretty" let's say so I'm trying to refactor this code to make more clean and simple

```
if (
      Object.values(this.searchParams.data)[0] === 'price_desc' ||
      Object.values(this.searchParams.data)[0] === 'price_asc'
    ) {
      // Do nothing
    } else if (!this.searchParams.data.price) {
      this.getProducts();
    }
```

with this one:

Considering that it's a Object like `{sortBy: "price_asc"}` or `{sortBy: "price_desc"}`

it shows in the terminal:

[image: object]

But we use the ES5 where I cannot use the `this.searchSortBy.includes()` because it will not work

So here my code:

```
var SponsoredProducts = (function() {
  function SponsoredProducts(
    this.searchParams = window.getSearch();

    this.searchSortBy = Object.values(this.searchParams.data)[0];

    console.log(this.searchParams.data.sortBy);
    console.log('-----------------------');
    console.log(this.searchSortBy);
    console.log('-----------1-----------');
    console.log(typeof this.searchSortBy.indexOf('price') === undefined);
    console.log('-----------2-----------');
    console.log(this.searchSortBy.indexOf('price') === "undefined");
    console.log('-----------3-----------');
    console.log(typeof this.searchSortBy.indexOf('price') == 
    if (!this.searchParams.data.price &&  String(this.searchSortBy).indexOf('price') == "-1") {
      this.getProducts();
    }

  }
```

But constantly I have problems that the error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

So there's a proper solution for this? I will be very grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: IndexOf will never return undefined, only -1 if it's not an index of the string it's used on.

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in your code. Please post working code which shows your problem.

Comment: Don’t edit your answer into the question.  Either add an answer if you think it will help someone or delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

The reason why it didn't work it is because I did not defined when the value comes empty/undefined so I add `|| ''` to create something even is empty so for the `indexOf` can check something to return `-1`

```
this.searchSortBy = this.searchParams.data.sortBy || '';

 if (
   !this.searchParams.data.price &&
   this.searchSortBy.indexOf('price') < 0
 ) {
   this.getProducts();
 }
```